# Unable to create a folder programatically

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-file

Below is the code that I'm using

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
File filepathname = new File(root+"/newfolder");
if(filepathname.mkdir())
    Toast.makeText(this,"directory created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(this,"directory not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I tried this code in Moto E (running Lollipop) and Nexus 5 (running marshmallow). Folder gets created in Moto but not in Nexus 5.

I have been able to create folder in Nexus 5 before upgrading to Marshmallow.

Is this a known problem in android M? Is there a work around? Or can anyone spot any problem in the code.

**Notes:**

1. The above mentioned code is in the `onCreate()` of my launcher activity,
2. The below permission is also there in the manifest file:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   ```
3. "newfolder" does not exist already.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: It's marshmallow issue. Your link is not valid here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion you dont have rights to create folder. If your application target is 23 or above you have to read about new runtime permissions.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html) you can find official documentation about it.