# How to create a new folder in android DCIM

Tags: android

I am actually able to capture a photo and to save it in android external storage DCIM folder.

My problem is that I can't create a new folder in it, so **DCIM/MyPic.jpg** became **DCIM/MyFolder/MyPic.jpg**.

Here is my source code :

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "address");

if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdir();
}

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     + File.separator
     + "DCIM"
     + File.separator
     + "address"
     + File.separator
     , "IMG_001.jpg");
```

Notice that I correctly asked for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest.

The intent part to capture photo is fine, because I can save it directly to DCIM.

I do not get any error message, but nothing happens... no 'address' folder created :(

Thanks for help :D

Comment: which target platform are you running on?

Comment: Min : 15, Target : 23. And I can mention that f.mkdir() always returns false.

Comment: I read this post but it doesn't help me to resolve my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212559/android-mkdir-returns-false

Comment: You need to ask for the permissions programmatically as per new permission model from API 23 + .

Comment: It does not solve the problem. Permission is granted. If not, I could not save a file directly in DCIM but I am able to.

Comment: Did you tried `mkdirs()` instead of `mkdir()` ?

Comment: Yes I do but I change it as explained in the link above.

Comment: DCIM folder is used when connecting the device as Camera. Are you using emulator or physical device ? If you are using physical device, what usb option did you choose ? Also note that the conventional directory to save shared pictures for you application is the DIRECTORY_PICTURES and not DIRECTORY_DCIM. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PICTURES

Comment: I use a physical device and when I run the app there is no usb connection. I use Drive to install it.

Comment: Same problem occurs in directory pictures. I am unable to create a subfolder

Comment: What is the android version of the device you are running the app on ? 
I just tried you code on an Android 6 and had the same problem until I asked for Runtime permission (new in Android 6)

Comment: I have a Nexus 5 running on 5.1.1 version

Comment: Can you post your manifest please ? Also, can we know how do you test if the folder was actually created or not ?

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.patrickmiller.test2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

    <application
   ...

Comment: I'm looking at the folder in Settings / Storage / Explorer / DCIM on the device

Comment: If your source code works, can you please show and explain it to give us the solution ? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure I will post it in an answer

Comment: consider reading this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431277/unable-to-create-a-folder-in-android-m-programatically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As posted in the comments, I tried your code and it worked for me.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "address");

        if (!f.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Folder doesn't exist, creating it...");
            boolean rv = f.mkdir();
            Log.d(TAG, "Folder creation " + ( rv ? "success" : "failed"));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Folder already exists.");
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tristan.testcreatedirectory">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Before launching the app I have to enable the permission manually because I am on Android 6.

** Logs when launching the app the first time **

```
D/MainActivity: Folder doesn't exist, creating it...
D/MainActivity: Folder creation success
```

** Logs when launching the app the second time **

```
D/MainActivity: Folder already exists.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but the same code do not work for me :( I am unable to create the directory and then save an image in it.

Comment: What are the logs when you run my code ? Can you paste it for me please ?

Comment: D/MainActivity: Folder doesn't exist, creating it...
D/MainActivity: Folder creation failed

Comment: Ok are you able to put a breakpoint in the mkdir function ? (not the call, the implementation). There should be a try/catch into it, with a return false in the catch clause. Put a breakpoint on the return false; line and debug your app. You should be able to see the value of the exception and why it doesn't want to create the folder.

Comment: I'll have a try tomorrow. Thanks for your time !

Comment: You were right ! My device is not on Marshmallow but I do target API 23 so requesting permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE programmatically was the solution ! I will post my source code as answer for further needs, but you get the credit for it !